# how to use a object key with " - " in the middle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

here is what the object looks like

```
  {
    approved_for_syndication: 1
    caption: ""
    copyright: ""
    media-metadata: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    subtype: "photo"  
                    }
```

how can i use `media-metadata` without syntax error

for example when i want to use it in a `map` function

```
array.map((item)=>{
     return item. //what can i use here?
 })
```

Comment: Put quotes around the key name `"media-metadata"` then to access it use the square bracket notation `obj["media-metadata"]`. I think something like this has been asked before, but I can't find it just yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While defining the array `media-metadata` inside `obj` it should be wrapped in `""` and when mapping over it then you need to use `[]` like

```js
const obj = {
  approved_for_syndication: 1,
  caption: "",
  copyright: "",
  "media-metadata": [{
    name: "test1"
  }, {
    name: "test2"
  }, {
    name: "test3"
  }],
  subtype: "photo",
};

const result = obj["media-metadata"].map((o) => o.name);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you wouldn't do that. I assume you're doing that to match the key as it's stored in some other medium. If that's the case, there are normally options to deserialize/serialize to a `camelCase` version of that `snake-case` name.

That said, if you must, you can wrap the key in quotes like this:

```json
copyright: "",
"media-metadata": ...
```

And you can access the corresponding value with `item['media-metadata']`.